# How to confirm that my GPU is running at full capacity? The GPU load is so low

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

My environment: windows10, tensorflow-gpu, single Nvidia RTX2070 (8GB memory), using tflearn to run AlexNet with the OxFlowers17 data set, batch_size=128.
I got this information:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGuQ7.png)

This means the GPU is running, right?
However, when I check the GPU usage with GPU-Z, the GPU load is low (The code is doing training, epoch information is being printed in the output window). Does this mean that my GPU is not running at full capacity?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heldO.gif)

After I closed PyCharm and with no big program running on my computer, the GPU usage is this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULyFf.png)

Then I have three questions:

1. The GPU load is low. Does this mean the GPU is not running at full capacity?
2. I forgot to set the gpu_memory_fraction. If I want to allocate a suitable gpu memory, how much should I set? (e.g. AlexNet with OxFlowers17 data set, the size of the data set is about 60MB.)
3. Why was the System Memory Used also so high? It has already used all the free gpu memory.

PS: This is the CPU (i5-8500) information when training:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JlkT.png)

Comment: Based on the stats, your GPU seems to be running, but there might be another bottleneck. What does CPU load look like?

Comment: is the code doing inference? if so then there is nothing to worry about, if you are training, gpu load should increase. Tensorflow by default allocate all GPU memory, so once you set the gpu_memory_fraction, it will reduce per your spec.

Comment: @user8408080: I have added the CPU information. Is there any problem then?

Comment: @teng: My code is training, but the GPU load is still so low. I edited my question again.

Comment: training data size is just 60MB... i thought this was a typo, but looks like it is just a small dataset, http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/flowers/17/ I don't think you need to be worried, you are just using a relatively good GPU that's all. If you still are not convinced, try varying the batch size to see if the gpu load changes.